# Active Directory Module: Retrieve members from multiple AD domains

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Sitecore 6.5, Update 6.  Active Directory Module 1.03 rev 111005

I'm trying to retrieve members from a particular group in AD and allow those users to log in and be assigned to roles in Sitecore.

I've been able to update my membership provider to use a customFilter to retrieve only those members who are in a specific group in domain 1 from AD.

The problem I'm having now is that there are members in that group that are members of domains (domain 2) that is not the domain (domain 1) where the group is held.  So when I look in User Manager, I don't see the members that are not a part of the domain (domain 1) where the group is held.

I added a separate membership provider and associated connection string to the domain (domain 2) that holds the other members in the group that I want, but I end up getting every member in that second domain instead of just the ones in the group from domain 1.  This second membership provider does not use the customFilter as the OUs and groups specified in the original filter do not apply to this domain.

Is there a way to get only the members from the group in domain 1 regardless of which domain the member actually resides?

Thanks!
Craig

Comment: For the time being, we are going to create groups in each domain and I will just use the "customFilter" for each provider entry to point to each of those groups.  It means more to manage for the IT staff, but it should work for what we need it to do.